# Difference between rows that share similar variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I have a table (c.14,000 or so rows / 100 or so columns) where the order cannot change. Each row is made unique by a number of columns, which I have simplified below.

Assume we have the below table, I need to create a new column that takes the difference between rows that share the same Col2/Col3 (but are unique by column 1). Ideally I do not want to touch the ordering to achieve this.

Note: in reality there are 7 variables which will match exactly, and 1 variable that will  leave it with two remaining.
i.e. the combined variable would be 2-A-A-A-A-A-A-A / 5-A-A-A-A-A-A-A. There is always only 2 remaining when the first 7 variables are identical, and I am looking at comparing these two.

Thanks!

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Percentage
     2       A       X        5%
     2       B       Y        4%
     2       C       Z        3%
     5       A       X        2%
     5       B       Y        1%
     5       C       Z        5%

   Desired:

   Col1    Col2    Col3    Percentage   Difference
      2       A       X        5%        3%   (*note: matches A/X to get 5%-2%=3%)
      2       B       Y        4%        3%      
      2       C       Z        3%       -2%
      5       A       X        2%        3%
      5       B       Y        1%        3%
      5       C       Z        5%       -2%
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, but I believe in an in-efficient manner!

I created a new dataframe

```
df2 = df[['Col1','Col2','Co3','Percentgage']]
```

Created a new column in df2 that is the mirror of column 1 (i.e. if 2 = 5, if 5 = 2)

```
df2['opposite_col1'] = np.where(df2['Col1']==2,5,2)
```

Removed the original column 1, and renamed the new column to be column 1

```
df2.drop('Col1',axis=1)
df2.columns = ['Col2,'Col3','Mirror_Percentgage','Col1']
```

This looks like this (note, identical to table 1 except the col1 is mirrored).

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Mirror_Percentage
 5       A       X        5%
 5       B       Y        4%
 5       C       Z        3%
 2       A       X        2%
 2       B       Y        1%
 2       C       Z        5%
```

Then simply merge df to df2 on Col1, Col2, Col3 - this leaves us with the original table except with an additional column of 'Mirror_Percentgage'.

I then create a new column that finds the margin:

```
df['Mirror_margin'] = df['Percentgage'] - df['Mirror_Percentgage']
```